# Como enviar informacion de un UserControl a un archivo JSON usando Json.net? en C# - WindowsForms

Tags: c#, json, .net, windows-forms

tengo un UserControl que creé dinámicamente desde la clase form principal del mismo proyecto. Necesito enviar toda la información (Nombre, Tags, posisiones etc) de ese UserControl que estoy creando dinámicamente a un archivo JSON. Estoy usando la libreria JSON.NET, estaba haciendo lo siguiente pero no funciona:

```
UserControl1 UC = new UserControl1();
string outputJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UC);
File.WriteAllText("mifile.json", outputJSON);
```

Comment: _No funciona_  que significa? Te da algún error? Los datos serializados no son correctos?

Comment: El error es el siguiente:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Self referencing loop detected for property 'Owner' with type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button'. 

Asumo que no puedo quizás serializar un UserControl completo.

Comment: Efectivamente. Un control cualquiera tiene literalmente cientos de propiedades,y serializar todas no es posible. Lo que debes hacer es serializar manualmente las que te interesen (posicion,tamaño,etc..) Tengo una respuesta preparada para ti,pero es extensa y hasta mañana no tendre acceso al equipo para ponerla.

Comment: Perfecto amigo, te espero entonces, de aquí no me muevo. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí va lo prometido.

Como te explico en mi comentario, un `Control` tiene cientos de propiedades, algunas específicas del tipo de `Control`, otras heredadas de la clase base `Control`,otras heredadas de `object`...Serializar todos estos datos es complicado y Json.Net no es capaz de hacerlo. Por otro lado, tampoco tiene mucho sentido serializar muchos de esos datos.

Te añado a continuación una solución. Es posible que pueda mejorarse, y definitivamente puedes modificarla para añadir otras propiedades que necesites almacenar, pero creo que te puede servir.

Primero comenzamos creando la clase que realmente va a ser serializada:

```
public class ControlSerializado
{
    public Type Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Texto { get; set; }
    public Point Posicion { get; set; }
    public Size Tamano { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Padre { get; set; }
    public List<ControlSerializado> Controles { get; set; }
}
```

Como ves, añado las propiedades que quiero almacenar. Probablemente te interese añadir otras, como el color de fondo etc...Eso queda a tu elección.

Ahora creamos el método que va a recorrer recursivamente todos los controles del control que se le pase:

```
public ControlSerializado Serializar(Control control)
{
    ControlSerializado cs = new ControlSerializado();
    cs.Nombre = control.Name;
    cs.Tipo = control.GetType();
    cs.Texto = control.Text;
    cs.Posicion = control.Location;
    cs.Tamano = control.Size;
    cs.Padre = control.Parent.Name;
    cs.Controles = new List<ControlSerializado>();
    foreach (var cont in control.Controls.Cast<Control>())
    {
        cs.Controles.Add(Serializar(cont));
    }
    return cs;
}
```

Como ves, va creando objetos de `ControlSerializado` mapeando las propiedades del control a la clase personalizada, y después recursivamente hace lo mismo con los controles hijos.

Un ejemplo de como se usaría:

```
//Creamos un user control de prueba
UserControl UC = new UserControl();
UC.Name = "UC1";
Panel p = new Panel();
p.Size = new Size(400, 400);
p.Location = new Point(0, 0);
p.Name = "Panel1";
Label lb1 = new Label();
lb1.Text = "Prueba";
lb1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
lb1.Name = "label1";
p.Controls.Add(lb1);
UC.Controls.Add(p);
this.Controls.Add(UC);

//Creamos nuestro ControlSerializado y llamamos a SerializeObject
var controlSerializado = Serializar(UC);
var serializado = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(controlSerializado);
```

En `serializado` tenemos ya el control con todos su hijos serializados para poder guardarles en un archivo por ejemplo.

---

Ahora vamos a recuperar los datos. Creamos un método que va leyendo el ControlPersonalizado recuperado y añadiéndolo a sus respectivos padres:

```
private void MostrarControl(ControlSerializado control,Control padre)
{
    //Buscamos el control Padre del que vamos a mostrar
    var controlPadre = (padre.Name == control.Padre) ? padre : padre.Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(x => x.Name == control.Padre).FirstOrDefault();
    //creamos el control
    var c = (Control)Activator.CreateInstance(control.Tipo);
    c.Name = control.Nombre;
    c.Text = control.Texto;
    c.Location = control.Posicion;
    c.Size = control.Tamano;
    controlPadre.Controls.Add(c);
    foreach(var hijo in control.Controles)
    {
        MostrarControl(hijo,c);
    }
}
```

Y por último, un ejemplo de uso:

```
var deserializado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ControlSerializado>(serializado);
MostrarControl(deserializado,this);
```

Espero que te haya quedado claro, podría extenderme un poco mas en las explicaciones pero creo que ya ha quedado la respuesta un poco extensa, si tienes alguna duda me comentas.

Comment: Amigazo, muchas gracias una vez mas, me demore en contestar porque fui analizando cosas y como soy nuevo en C# cuesta, pero me sirvió bastante, gracias por darte la vuelta larga y explicar muchas cosas.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la librería [NEWTONSOFT](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Aqui un ejemplo de como podría ser.

```
MiClase c = new MiClase();
c.Nombre= UC.txtnombre.text;
c.Tags = UC.tags.toArray();
c.Posesiones= UC.posesiones.toArray();

string outputJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c);
// {
//   "Nombre": "...",
//   "Tags": [],
//   "Posesiones": []
// }
File.WriteAllText("mifile.json", outputJSON);
```

Comment: Amigo tu código es el mismo mio, solo que no puse la asignación de las propiedades para no alargar el ejemplo, asimismo, estoy usando la librería Json.net, que justamente el propietario es Newtonsoft.

Comment: Te equivocas. Aunque sea un codigo parecido, utilizo la herramienta NEWTONSOFT.

Comment: Podrias revisar bien la docu y leer un poco mas. De todos modos no sirve tu respuesta porque es lo mismo....

Comment: En tu descripcion lo que pedias era serializar un control, cosa que hace mi codigo pero con otra librería.